# What is the SQL query to show the number of tables in a database?

Tags: mysql

I can use `SHOW TABLES` to list the tables, but how can I get only the number of tables in a given database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(table_name) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW TABLES
```

The `SHOW TABLES` command will list the tables in your database

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-tables.html